# Azure Powershell: Get-AzureADUser othermails not visible

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, windows-authentication

When I run the `get-AzureADUser -objectID someone@contoso.com | Select Displayname,Othermails` I cannot see the othermails property. The property turns up as:

OtherMails: {}

I would like to see this property, to check if everyone in the organisation has an authentication method filled in. So they can use the SSPR.

I am using the tenant administrator account. So I should be able to see everything. In the GUI of Azure AD, when I click on a user and authentication methods. I can see that the emailaddress is there. But it turns up blanc in Powershell.

Anyone has a clue why this is?

Comment: That will only show the proxyaddresses and smtp's used, like x400 and x500 etc. But I want to see the private emailadresses, which they can use to manage their passwords (SSPR). If those are blanc, then users will get annnoying popups :)

Comment: It will show nothing, because it is blanc. The alternateemailaddresses are the aliases I think. They are not used as authentication method. I can see with get-member, that the OtherMails has a NoteProperty. I have a faint idea, that the property is hidden or sometething.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting SSPR information you need to use `Get-MsolUser` cmdlet. The data included under `StrongAuthenticationUserDetails` is the one you can see under *Authentication methods*:

```
$t = Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName upn@domain.com
$t.StrongAuthenticationUserDetails

# Returns

ExtensionData          : System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject
AlternativePhoneNumber :
Email                  : email@gmail.com
OldPin                 :
PhoneNumber            : +48 123456789
Pin                    :
```

There are other fields, which can be used for SSPR (such as alternate email address), but they won't be displayed under *Authentication methods*.

Comment: Bingo. I had to import-module msonline first. But after that I got the right cmdlets. And this shows the strongauthentication methods :) I tried using the alternate email address field at first, but it didn't seem to work for SSPR. We are creating users by using ESB / RBAC solutions. And only the Set-AzureADUser -othermails worked for SSPR. Thank you so much!